# Create database permission denied in database 'master' SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, angularjs, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to make an simple demo of login same like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1032226/CRUD-Operation-in-ASP-NET-MVC-and-AngularJS

but on load of page I get an error:

> create database permission denied in database 'master'

I searched everything but no luck..

My connection string is:

```
<add name="BookManagementEntities" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SUPP-INF-DEV-05\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BookManage;Integrated Security=SSPI;user id=sa;password=admin@123;" />
```

Why is this happening, and how to solve it?

**Edit:** I tried every solution on first page after googling this error but still got same error..

Comment: As error suggests. you have no permissions to create database.

Comment: I have already created and connected to VS while doing CRUD operation i am getting this error

Comment: Check in sql express by creating one sample database. see what you have.

Comment: I can create table in sql express..I do not want to create table..I already did that I just want to fetch data from table

Comment: You can create table in sql express. but can you create database?

Comment: Yes i can create database.I am getting this error while I am fetching all records from database

Comment: Well - seems like you're still trying to create when "fetching"

Comment: What I have to do now :s @AllanS.Hansen

Comment: Impossible to say without showing your code

Answer (score 0):

I know for sure that SA is a sysadmin within SQL server and it must not have any permissions issues during its use, also it's well known that we should not be using SA as a SQL account to connect to the instance for application purposes, instead we must create another account with dbo/sysadmin depending on the operation we are trying to achieve, can you please create another account same permissions as SA or try using Windows Authentication (of course with permissions enable)